# how to collate an input from the users and store it localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I've been trying to store an array from the the users input into localstorage and the output is not really encouraging as it gives inappropriate result:

```
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="text" value=" " class="ex" >
    <button id="ex">add item </button>
</form>
```

```
const items2 = document.querySelector('form');
items2.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  const items1 = document.getElementsByClassName('ex').value;
  let items3;
  if (localStorage.getItem('items3') === null) {
    items3 = [];
  } else {
    items3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items3'));
  }
  localStorage.setItem('items3', JSON.stringify(items3));
  items3.push(items1);

  alert('submit');
  ev.preventDefault();
});

const items3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items3'));
items3.forEach(function(items1) {
  console.log(items1);
});
```

so, the problem I am facing exactly is that the alert always respond each time I click on the button which is but the localStorage file keeps giving the same value as an empty array [] regardless of any value I input into the text container. The forEach is also returning an error of

> cannot read properties of an empty of null ('forEach')

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('ex')` returns a live HTMLCollection. It doesn't have a value in itself; you'll need to iterate over it to retrieve values or specify an index, such as `document.getElementsByClassName('ex')[0].value`

Comment: You are getting, "cannot read properties of an empty of null ('forEach')", because you don't have value yet. So you might need to do a check for that.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you run the script, nothing has been saved to local storage, so

```
const items3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items3'));
```

will set `items3` to `null`. That needs to have error checking to create a default value.

The submit listener needs to save to local storage *after* pushing the new item into the array.

There's no need to call `localStorage.getItem()` in the listener. You can just use the global `items3` variable that's set when you read from local storage at the beginning.

```js
const items2 = document.querySelector('form');
items2.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  const items1 = document.getElementsByClassName('ex').value;
  items3.push(items1);
  localStorage.setItem('items3', JSON.stringify(items3));

  alert('submit');
  ev.preventDefault();
});

const items3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items3') || '[]');
items3.forEach(function(items1) {
  console.log(items1);
});
```

```html
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="text" value=" " class="ex" >
    <button id="ex">add item </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response , it does work tho it returns series of empty array but before it returns just a single array, i'll try to find my way out around this.....thank you once again

Comment: I accidentally removed the code that sets `items1`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get null is because, `document.getElementsByClassName('ex')` returns a HTMLCollection. So, when you do `document.getElementsByClassName('ex').value` it doesn't contain a value but an object and then returns `null`; you'll need to iterate over it to retrieve values or specify an index, such as `document.getElementsByClassName('ex')[0].value` or better still, `document.getElementById('ex').value`

Here's a fix for you.

```
<form>
  <input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" class="firstName" />
  <button id="ex">add items</button>
</form>
```

```
const items2 = document.querySelector("form");
items2.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let items1 = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  // or let items1 = document.getElementsByClassName("firstName")[0].value;
  items3.push(items1);
  localStorage.setItem("items3", JSON.stringify(items3));
  document.getElementById("firstName").value = "";
  alert("name added successfully")
});

const items3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items3") || "[]");
items3.forEach(function (items1) {
  console.log(items1);
});
```

Comment: Give this a thumbs up if it helped you.